# Find out the letter frequency in from a list in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x, frequency

I'm trying to code a program that will count the occurence of different chars in a list. I want to find the 7 most common once and also want to count the % of the occurence of that letter of the total amount of letters.

```
fileOpen = open("lol.txt", 'r')
savedWordData = fileOpen.read()
fileOpen.close()

#To split into chars and function to clear the string from faulty chars
savedWordData = cleanString(savedWordData)
savedWordData = savedWordData.replace(" ", "")
#print(savedWordData)


#Use this to count the total number of chars and find the 7 most common once
from collections import Counter
data = Counter(savedWordData)
print("The 7 most common letters: "  + str(data.most_common(7)))
sumOfAll = sum(data.values())
```

But not sure how I should continue from here. How do I access the values from the data dict so I can see the occurrence of each letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), and then loop on the list to get the values :

```
In [35]: s = 'ieufisjhfkdfhgdfkjvwoeiweuieanvszudadyuieafhuskdjfhdviurnawuevnskzjdvnziurvzdkjHFiuewhksjnvviuzsdiufwekfvnxkjvnsdv'

In [36]: l = list(s)

In [37]: from collections import Counter

In [38]: data = Counter(l)

In [39]: data.most_common()
Out[39]: 
[('u', 11),
 ('v', 11),
 ('d', 10),
 ('i', 10),
 ('k', 8),
 ('e', 8),
 ('f', 8),
 ('s', 7),
 ('j', 7),
 ('n', 7),
 ('z', 5),
 ('w', 5),
 ('h', 5),
 ('a', 4),
 ('r', 2),
 ('g', 1),
 ('H', 1),
 ('y', 1),
 ('x', 1),
 ('o', 1),
 ('F', 1)]

In [40]: for i in range(0, 7):
    ...:     print(data.most_common()[i])
    ...:     
('u', 11)
('v', 11)
('d', 10)
('i', 10)
('k', 8)
('e', 8)
('f', 8)
```

The first value is the letter, the second one is the number of occurrence.

Comment: Yeah exacatly how i want! Now I just need to figure out how I can extract the number of times each of the most common letters occure, and then divide it with the total sum of all letters to get my precent

Comment: @anderssinho you can use `len(data)` to get the number of **different** letters in the text. Is this what you need though ? I'm not entirely sure about your definition of the "total sum of all letters"...

Comment: Just pass `7` as an argument `data.most_common(7)`

Comment: @3kt
I mean that I want to calculate the procent of the times for example the letter 'e' occure in the total amount of letters.
So if there is 100 letters and 'e' occurs 10 times, I want to calculate and print out something like:
"E is 10% of the total amout of letters in the list"

Comment: @anderssinho in my example, to count the total number of letter, you just need to do `len(l)` then.

Comment: @Chris_Rands you're absolutely right, but I was unsure about whether the OP wanted to use the count of the other letters or not, hence I only included a link to the documentation.

Comment: Sorry if my explanations where a bit unclear. But now I solved the problem thanks to you guys